# Blazor automatic sign in based on token in url

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'd like to allow my site to run in an iframe, where the parent of the iframe provides a security token in the url to identify the user (the user can also use the site outside of the iframe with their login and password if they prefer).

After I've checked the url token is valid, and it matches an existing user I want to try something like:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("username", "password", ...)
}
```

The result says the signin is successful but it's not. If I check the authentication state after the PasswordSignInAsync no user is signed in.

Is it possible to do this with blazor server rendered code?

I'm aware it's not particularly secure btw.

Answer (score 0):

The authenticationstate hasn't refreshed yet.
You could try get user information from `IdentityUserAccessor`

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
```

```
@inject IdentityUserAccessor accessor
...
@code{
...
   var user=accessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
}
```